# map/dplyr way for dynamically populating two columns in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have the dataframe 'test' as shown at very bottom below.

I have 2 different operations Id like to complete on two different columns and would like to use an efficient dplyr or purrr method to resolve, if possible.

Operation#1:
Id like to populate 'amt_needed' NA values to be the two values from 'remaining' above it (this is a test dataframe, but in actual version Ill have more rows and each time Id like the two 'amt_needed' values to be = to the two values from 'remaining' in the above two rows).

Operation #2:
The two NA values for 'remaining' should be the new 'amt_needed' values - sum(contrib) for both a and b.

Any thoughts/suggestions appreciated!

```
test <- data.frame(date = c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-15", "2018-01-15"), 
                   name = c("a","b","a","b"), 
                   contrib = c(4,2,4,2), 
                   amt_needed = c(100,100, NA,NA), 
                   remaining = c(94,94, NA,NA))
```

Comment: Are you able to include an 'after' dataset to help with understanding your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on new data provided in OP, one solution using dplyr could be :

```
    library(dplyr)
    # Data
test <- data.frame(date = c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-15", "2018-01-15", "2018-01-30", "2018-01-30"), 
                   name = c("a","b","a","b", "a","b"), 
                   contrib = c(4,2,4,2,4,2), 
                   amt_needed = c(100,100, NA,NA, NA,NA), 
                   remaining = c(94,94, NA,NA, NA,NA))

    # Change column to date
    test$date <- as.Date(test$date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    test$amt_needed <- test$amt_needed[1]

test %>%
  arrange(date, name) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(group_contrib = cumsum(sum(contrib))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(date, group_contrib) %>%
  unique() %>% 
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(cumm_group_sum = cumsum(group_contrib)) %>%
  inner_join(test, by = "date") %>% 
  mutate(remaining = amt_needed - cumm_group_sum) %>%
  mutate(amt_needed_act = remaining + group_contrib) %>%
  select(date, name, contrib, amt_needed_act, remaining)

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  date       name   contrib amt_needed_act remaining
  <date>     <fctr>   <dbl>          <dbl>     <dbl>
1 2018-01-01 a         4.00          100        94.0
2 2018-01-01 b         2.00          100        94.0
3 2018-01-15 a         4.00           94.0      88.0
4 2018-01-15 b         2.00           94.0      88.0
5 2018-01-30 a         4.00           88.0      82.0
6 2018-01-30 b         2.00           88.0      82.0
```

Comment: thanks for this idea, its a helpful start but as you guessed, need a looping type function for larger data set.  I posted a better test example here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513738/loop-through-dataframe-and-run-lag-on-each-row-col-value-that-is-na

Comment: @user5831311 You dont need a loop. Look at the `result` included in my answer. Both `NA` values are replaced. Try this solution on your dataframe and check result. Another question is not needed as it will confuse future users. If you have a different problem then only post another question.

Comment: please test out your proposed solution on the longer dataframe I posted in the new question.  Your solution does not resolve it - this is why I think a for loop (or ideally, vectorized approach) is needed.

Comment: @user5831311 You could have added new data frame in this question itself otherwise it will get down-voted. Anyway please update desired output and I'll have a look.

Comment: @user5831311 I have updated my answer to take care of modified dataset. It will work for any length of data-set now. Your question was very good but it lacked details. You can modify your question to represent nicely.